# How can i use a thread to pull all new notifications in my database every x amount of time

Tags: c#, database, multithreading

I want to pull a list of notifications every 15 seconds from my database without making my program very slow

This list of notifications will then be displayed using a popup notifier

The problem I am facing is that when I call the method to show the popups if shows the popup on the secondary thread and not on the main thread

I have tried alot of ways around it like using an event and invoking the event whenever the time elapsed but that just call the event handler on the secondary thread the one thing that i have been able to achieve is using a message box in that same method as the popup notifier but that looks bad and defies the purpose of the backend procees

```
  // This is the form that should show the notifications 
    private void Student_Details_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WinAPI.AnimateWindow(this.Handle, 200, WinAPI.BLEND);
        notifications.NewNotification += OnNewNotification;
        //This is a list of notifiactions        
        allNotifications = notifications.GetNotifications(StudentFound.Student.Person_ID);
        // calling the method to start the thread
         notifications.ShowNotifications();
        //This was an attempt to get it right
        //Thread notififcationThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
        //{

        //    while (true)
        //    {
        //        AllNotifications = new 
         Notifications().GetNotifications(StudentFound.Student.Person_ID);

        //        //MethodInvoker invoker = new 
        MethodInvoker(showNotifications);
        //        //invoker.Invoke();
        //        //showNotifications();
        //        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        //    }
        //}));

        //notififcationThread.Start();

    }

    public void OnNewNotification(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You have notifications");
        PopupNotifier popup = new PopupNotifier();
        popup.Image = Properties.Resources.About_104px;
        popup.TitleText = "Smart Shool System";
        foreach (Notifications item in allNotifications)
        {
            popup.ContentText = item.Notification_Text;
            popup.Popup();
        }
    }

  // The method in the class that pulls the data
  public List<Notifications> GetNotifications(string userFound)
    {
        List<Notifications> allNotifications = new List<Notifications>();
        DataHandler dataHandler = new DataHandler();
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

            dataTable = dataHandler.GetNotifications(userFound);
            foreach (DataRow rowItem in dataTable.Rows)
            {
                allNotifications.Add(new Notifications(int.Parse(rowItem["Notification_Id"].ToString()),
                    rowItem["Notification_text"].ToString(),
                    rowItem["Person_ID"].ToString(),
                    bool.Parse(rowItem["Notification_Status"].ToString())));
            }

        return allNotifications;

    }

  //EventHandler
    private void OnNewNotification()
    {
        if (NewNotification !=null)
        {
            NewNotification(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
  //This is my current attempt this method is called in the frontend

    public void ShowNotifications()
    {
        //OnNewNotification();
        Thread notififcationThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
        {

            while (true)
            {
                OnNewNotification();
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
            }
        }));
        notififcationThread.Start();

     }
```

Comment: The UI is Wpf or WinForms?

Comment: The application is in WinForms and the database is in SQL server 2014

Answer (score 0):

You can do this on one thread with async-await.

```
private CancellationTokenSource _displayNotification;
private Task _displayNotificationTask;

public StudentDetailsForm()
{
    _displayNotification = new CancellationTokenSource();
}

private void Student_Details_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _displayNotificationTask = DisplayNotification(_displayNotification.Token);
}

private async void Student_Details_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    _displayNotification.Cancel();
    await _displayNotificationTask;
}

private async Task DisplayNotifications(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    while (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested == false)
    {
        await LoadAndDisplayNotification();
        await Task.Delay(15000, cancellationToken);
    }
}

private async Task LoadAndDisplayNotification()
{
    // Load data and display it.
}
```

And you need to change your loading notification code to be asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you could do it. You use a WinForms timer that raises an event every 15 secs calling your event handler. Your event handler runs on the UI thread and so you can do whatever you want to update the UI. You can retrieve the data in a background thread, and display it with code in the event handler.

```
public partial class MyForm
{
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer _timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

    public MyForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // ...

        _timer.Interval = 15000; // Run Tick(s, e) event handler every 15 secs.
        _timer.Tick +=
            (s, e) =>
            {
                // Here you put whatever code you want to run at 15 secs
                // interval. Code is run on UI thread, so you can update
                // UI at will.
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm struggling to understand the flow that you want with your code, but here's the way I would tackle any UI update like this.

You should use Microsoft's Reactive Framework (aka Rx) - NuGet `System.Reactive.Windows.Forms` and add `using System.Reactive.Linq;` - then you can do this:

```
IDisposable subscription =
    Observable
        .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0))
        .SelectMany(x => Observable.Start(() => GetTextData()))
        .ObserveOn(this)
        .Subscribe(x => control.Text = x);
```

Super simple.

You can call `subscription.Dispose()` to stop the timer.